# Connecting to Azure Sql Server from Access linked tables using AAD

Tags: azure, ms-access

Is it possible to connect to Azure Sql Server database from Access using 'Sql Server Native Agent' driver and Azure Active Directory authentication?

I can connect using Odbc driver for Sql Server but if in Access I have problem with date and datetime2 columns (they are seen by Access as text fields instead datetime)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue of older SQL server ODBC drivers.

Use a more recent ODBC driver. An overview of versions can be found on [This MS Docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server-on-windows?view=sql-server-2017)